# How do I transfer my Minecraft account to my new PC and add a different account to the old PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just got a new computer for Christmas and I want to transfer my Minecraft PC account to the new one. My sister would like to have her own account on my old computer. My sister also doesn't have an account. So with my old computer, she wants to make a brand new account but my account is already there. How can I transfer the old account to the new computer and create a new account on the old computer? I am running Minecraft 1.11.2 and Windows is on both PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft accounts aren't connected to a PC. The launcher will helpfully remember your login for you, but this is only a convenience — your account isn't locked to it. You can just log in on your new PC and you will be able to play.

Your sister will need to have a new paid account. When she does, she can ignore your old account on the old PC and log in with her new account and be able to play.